# Moving a Do Until function across columns in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm pretty new to VBA and having trouble creating a quick macro used to move blocks of numbers around.

What I am trying to create is a button that when pressed:

Moves the contents of (i,5) to E63

The cells from (i, 16) down to F67:F110

Dependant on whether Row 10 contains "Low" or "High" moves three cells from the set 
N106:N109 to the cells (i12:i14) [Where i is the column reference).

The Range sections of code are what accomplish this and they are working fine, the problem I am having is with my Do.Until row and with the reference Column(i)

Does anyone know how this could work? Thanks

**UPDATE**
So thanks to the help of Siddharth I've been able to fix all but one bit, which is the lines where there is a string in the Range function. The reason I am not using .Formula here but Paste instead is that otherwise all of the cells A12:A14 to Z12:Z14 will equal the same thing which isn't correct. On the other parts that doesn't matter. I am getting a type 13 mismatch error on these lines.

```
Sub Columntest()
Dim i As Integer
    i = 5
    Do Until Cells(5, i).Value = ""
        If Cells(10, i).Value = "Low" Then
                   Range("E63").Formula = Cells(5, i)
                   Range("F67:F110").Formula = Cells(16, i)
                   Range("O106:O108").Copy
                   Range("=" & Columns(i) & "12").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End If
        If Cells(10, i).Value = "High" Then
                   Range("E63").Formula = Cells(5, i)
                   Range("F67:F110").Formula = Cells(16, i)
                   Range("N106:N108").Copy
                   Range(Columns(i) & "12").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End If
    i = i + 1
    Loop
```

End Sub

Comment: Birds View: Shouldn't you be incrementing `i` i.e `i = i + 1`? Also `Next` with `Do`? And why a DOT before `Cells`?

Comment: Now I can see so many errors :) Why `Column` and not `Columns`? How is `Range("=" & Column(i) & "10")` a range... Can you attach a sample and show what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The type mismatch is because you are trying to concatenate a column object and a string in the range reference:

```
Range("=" & Columns(i) & "12").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Try using this instead:

```
Cells(12, i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```